# How to check from the memcached ticket registry if a user already log in to CAS or not?

Tags: java, spring-security, hash, memcached, cas

We are using CAS 5.3.9 at the moment. We have applications that are using CAS protocol as well as CAS REST protocol. For applications that are using the CAS REST protocol (specially mobile application) we want to check if the user is already log in to CAS sso. If so then we want to let the user authenticate. We are using a memcached ticket registry. How can we check from memcached if the user has already log in to CAS or not?

I want to make a web service that will act as a proxy in between CAS and the applications that are using CAS REST protocol. This web service will check whether the user log in to CAS or not. For that I can connect to memcached and get the stats of the slabs and the items in memcached. From there I can get the value using items as key but It is encrypted using FNV1_64_HASH hash Algorithm and KRYO serialization. The value looks similar to a ticket granting cookie. Using the CAS Rest protocol I can get a ticket granting ticket and service ticket for a service, validate the service ticket and get the CAS response for a user. Now I want to check against the memcached whether that user is already logged in to CAS or not.

This is my memcached configuration for CAS

```
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.servers=mymemcached:11211
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.locatorType=CONSISTENT
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.failureMode=Redistribute
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.hashAlgorithm=FNV1_64_HASH
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.shouldOptimize=false
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.daemon=true
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.maxReconnectDelay=-1
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.useNagleAlgorithm=false
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.shutdownTimeoutSeconds=-1
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.opTimeout=-1
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.timeoutExceptionThreshold=2
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.maxTotal=20
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.maxIdle=8
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.minIdle=0
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.transcoder=KRYO
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.transcoderCompressionThreshold=16384
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.kryoAutoReset=false
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.kryoObjectsByReference=false
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.kryoRegistrationRequired=false

cas.ticket.registry.memcached.crypto.signing.key=mykey
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.crypto.signing.keySize=512
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.crypto.encryption.key=mykey
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.crypto.encryption.keySize=16
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.crypto.alg=AES
cas.ticket.registry.memcached.crypto.enabled=true
```

I want to know how memcached is actually storing the tickets so that I can check for users if there is a ticket already present for them or not

Answer (score 0):

> We have applications that are using CAS protocol as well as CAS REST protocol. For applications that are using the CAS REST protocol (specially mobile application)

So this means your applications get access to a TGT that is issued by CAS. So long as this TGT is considered valid by the CAS server, you can manage an SSO session based on it and consider the user logged in. Remember that when using REST, the SSO session management is entirely left onto the application; if the user logs out in your application, you need to contact CAS to kill the TGT.

> we want to check if the user is already log in to CAS sso. If so then we want to let the user authenticate. We are using a memcached ticket registry.

Write an endpoint in CAS that accepts the TGT and checks for the validity of the TGT in the CAS ticket registry using the `TicketRegistry` api. If the ticket can be valid and hasn't expired yet, your endpoint can produce a response.

[Relevant blog post](https://apereo.github.io/2019/06/14/cas53x-userlogin-ssostatus/) might help.

PS Always specify the software version in your posts.

Comment: Sorry about that, We are using CAS 5.3.9 at the moment.